# Parse a web page with button "Load More" with python

Tags: python, parsing, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract all the comments on a movie from this page https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114709/reviews?ref_=tt_ql_3 but some of them are hidden behind a button "Load More", I have tried with selenium to to click on this button but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my code and the error message, if someone has an idea on how to achieve that.

````
h = httplib2.Http("./docs/.cache")
resp, content = h.request(url, "GET")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
divs = soup.find_all("div")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
while driver.find_elements_by_class_name("load-more-data"):
      driver.find_elements_by_name("Load More").click()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/demo/PycharmProjects/untitled/Extraction.py", line 567, in <module>
    Mat()
  File "C:/Users/demo/PycharmProjects/untitled/Extraction.py", line 518, in Mat
    dicoCam =testC.extract_data()
  File "C:/Users/demo/PycharmProjects/untitled/Extraction.py", line 368, in extract_data
    self.extract_comment(movie, url)
  File "C:/Users/demo/PycharmProjects/untitled/Extraction.py", line 469, in extract_comment
    driver.find_elements_by_name("Load More").click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'```
````

Comment: Does pressing the button open a new link in the webbrowser? You could extract the comments from there.

Comment: No, it doesn't change the url

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the error is, you search it with `find_elements_by_name`, beware of element**s**, so it returns a list since you are asking it to find multiple elements. If you want to click "Load More" button infinitely, I suggest:

```py
while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("load-more-data").click()
    except selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotFoundException:
        break
```

I'm not sure if the class names are true though since they are based on your example. I didn't inspect the web page you gave. You can alter my code for your situation if it won't work.

Comment: I got this :selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (508, 576)
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.88)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the error message, a list is returned when doing:

```
driver.find_elements_by_name("Load More")
```

That's why I suggest doing this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_name("Load More")[0].click()
```

You have to make sure that there is only 1 element named `Load More`.

If this is not the case, increase the list index `[0]` by 1 for each element

named `Load More`.

**Hope that helped.**

**EDIT**: If you still get error messages, like `list index out of range` , the `driver.find_elements_by_name()` function isn't working the proper way you want it to.

I'm not an expert when dealing with the Internet with Python, 
but you should look for

functions like
`driver.find_elements_by_innerhtml()` or `driver.find_elements_by_text()`.

Is there any function like that?